# lvm: lvresize --resizefs does not read the request size in correctly

Tags: linux, shell, architecture, filesystems, lvm

I am trying to resize a logical volume (as well as the filesystem contained on that volume) and am a little confused by the output of the `lvresize` command:

```
# lvresize --resizefs -L 2T /dev/archive/archive
  File system ext4 found on archive/archive mounted at /mnt.
  File system size (<4,55 TiB) is larger than the requested size (0   ).
  File system reduce is required using resize2fs.
  File system unmount is needed for reduce.
  File system fsck will be run before reduce.
Continue with ext4 file system reduce steps: unmount, fsck, resize2fs? [y/n]:n
  File system not reduced.
```

I wanted to resize the logical volume of 5T down to 2T but this particular line gives me worries:   `File system size (<4,55 TiB) is larger than the requested size (0   )`.

What is even wierder is that the output changes in, as it seems to me, mysterious ways:

trying 2000G instead of 2T gives the requested size of 1.95TiB

```
# lvresize --resizefs -L 2000G /dev/archive/archive
  File system ext4 found on archive/archive mounted at /mnt.
  File system size (<4,55 TiB) is larger than the requested size (1,95 TiB).
  File system reduce is required using resize2fs.
  File system unmount is needed for reduce.
  File system fsck will be run before reduce.
Continue with ext4 file system reduce steps: unmount, fsck, resize2fs? [y/n]:n
  File system not reduced.
```

trying 3000G gives a requested size of 952GiB

```
# lvresize --resizefs -L 3000G /dev/archive/archive
  File system ext4 found on archive/archive mounted at /mnt.
  File system size (<4,55 TiB) is larger than the requested size (952,00 GiB).
  File system reduce is required using resize2fs.
  File system unmount is needed for reduce.
  File system fsck will be run before reduce.
Continue with ext4 file system reduce steps: unmount, fsck, resize2fs? [y/n]:n
  File system not reduced.
```

I have not accepted any of these commands as there is still infomation stored on the disks.

For some added context:

I am doing this because I want to remove a drive from a volume group, but to use `pvmove` i first need to clear up some physical extends.

As far as I understood it the logical volumes allocates physical extends, which means I just need to reduce the size of the logical volume before running `pvmove`.

I have two drives with one physical volume each `sda1` and `sdb1` both are joined into a volume group called `archive` which has a logical volume also called `archive`.

The logical volume takes up the entirety of the volume group.

I was mainly referencing the arch linux wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/LVM#Resizing_the_logical_volume_and_file_system_in_one_go

At this point I don't know if this is a bug, even though I highly doubt it considering the popularity of lvm.

Comment: Unmount the file system, run fsck, then check its size. Seems like something went wrong in first command.  Second looks ok due to difference between TB and TiB.

Comment: which still does not explain the output of the third command. i ran `fsck` before and it reported no problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

This was in fact a error in how lvm calulated disk sizes.

I am using arch, where i enabled the tesing mirrors inside `/etc/pacman.conf`.

after that, just updating lvm2 fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue. Using:
Arch Linux 6.6.8

Looking at an answer from this post:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/766066/lvresize-showing-incoherent-and-random-final-size
You can run:

```
--fs ignore
```

Comment: ok, so this is acutually a bug in lvm. but setting `--fs ignore` is counterproductive becuase i wanted to resize the filesystem with `--resizefs`. but if this will be fixed in a later release i can just wait for that